# Is there a way to manage floating numbers in lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda

I am currently working on a project at my college, where I get a stream of information about a patients heart sound. The Arduino Client is measuring the sound of the heart of a patient and sending the data via LAN to my server. The server decodes the String of numbers and uses it to draw a graph with matplotlib. My problem is the following:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import datetime
import sys

converter = lambda data: (data[0], data[1]/1023*5, data[2]/1000)

HOST = ''
PORT = 1236
address = (HOST, PORT)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.style.use('seaborn')
plt.tight_layout()
fig.show()

x, y = [], []

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.bind((address))
    s.listen(1)
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print(f"Connectet to Client {addr}")
        try:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(4096).decode("utf-8")
                if data == "STOP":
                    break
                else:
                    data_list = data.split(";")
                    for d in data_list:
                        data_point = d.split(",")
                        if len(data_point) > 3:
                            data_point = ''
                        else:
                            data_point_num = [float(i) for i in data_point]
                            print(type(data_point_num))
                            real_data = list(map(converter, data_point_num))

        finally:
            sys.exit()
```

As you can see, that I am trying to convert the Sound Voltage into actual Voltage with a lambda expression. However, I am getting the Traceback error that float is not subscriptable. Can anybody help a student out?

If the `split()` function is confusing, it's because the client sends a string with three values, packed in an even bigger string. Example:

```
b'0,765,18273;0,721,18274;0,750,18275;....'
```

and so on.

If you have specific tips and tricks to say about my project, then please do, because I am new to Python

Comment: `data_point_num` is a list of floats, you then pass the lambda and the list of floats to map. Map will take each float from the list and pass each one individually to your lambda. So lambda receives just a single float. which you then try to do `data[0]` but data here is a float and as the error says, thats not subscriptable. You seem to be thinking a list is being passed to the convertor lambda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Doyle is right. You are passing a list of floats to the 'map' with the function converter. The map will iterate over each element of this list, each of which is a float. However, for each element, the function converter will try to subscript it, which is why you are getting that error. I think what you mean to do is something like this:

```
data_list = data.split(';')
updated_data_list = []
for d in data_list:
    data_point = d.split(',')
    if len(data_point) > 3:
        data_point = ''
    else:
        data_point_num = [float(i) for i in data_point]
        updated_data_list.append(data_point_num)
real_data = list(map(converter, updated_data_list))
```

In this code, 'updated_data_list' is a list of lists. This will be passed to the function converter by calling map, which will apply the function converter to each list within 'updated_data_list'. Since each list is subscriptable, this should get around the error and I think this is what you intended to achieve originially (although this will still cause a problem if any of your data points have fewer than three parts).

Answer (score 0):

Python map takes in a list, and processes each element with the function provided.

For example:

```
# Return square of x 
def square(x): 
    return x**2 

numbers = [13, 21, 39, 24, 100]
result = map(square, numbers) 
print(list(result)) 

# same implementation using lambda
result = map(lambda x: x**2, numbers)
print(list(result))
```

Correct implementation to your code.

```
# input data
data = "0,765,18273;0,721,18274;0,750,18275;"
# split based on ';' and removing the empty at the end
data_list = data.split(";")[:-1]

# inserting a list of list 
# [['0', '765', '18273'], ['0', '721', '18274'], ['0', '750', '18275']]
for i in range(len(data_list)):
  data_list[i] = data_list[i].split(",")

converter = lambda data: (float(data[0]),float(data[1])/1023*5,float(data[2])/1000)
real_data = list(map(converter, data_list))

print(real_data)
```